# Fazer INNER JOIN com com mais de uma tabela

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

EU quero relacionar fazer inner join na tabela Funcionário com Endereço, E departamento e função mas só que a tabela função é chave estrangeira na tabela departamento[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

**INNER JOIN no C#**

```
SqlDataAdapter QIG4A = new SqlDataAdapter();
                string sql4A = "SELECT DP.ID_DEPARTAMENTO, DP.NOME_DEP, FUNCAO.NOME_FUNCAO, FUNCAO.SALARIO FROM DEPARTAMENTO AS DP INNER JOIN FUNCAO ON DP.ID_FUNCAO = FUNCAO.ID_FUNCAO;";
                DataTable tb4A = new DataTable();
                QIG4A = new SqlDataAdapter(sql4A, Q1.SMS());
                QIG4A.Fill(tb4A);
                comboBoxEx3.DataSource = tb4A;
                comboBoxEx3.DisplayMember = "NOME_DEP";
                comboBoxEx4.DataSource = tb4A;
                comboBoxEx4.DisplayMember = "NOME_FUNCAO";
                comboBoxEx18.DataSource = tb4A;
                comboBoxEx18.DisplayMember = "SALARIO";
                comboBoxEx19.DataSource = tb4A;
                comboBoxEx19.DisplayMember = "ID_DEPARTAMENTO";
```

as tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE FUNCIONARIO
(
    ID_FUNCIONARIO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_FUNCIONARIO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    NOME_PAI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    NOME_MAE VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    N_BI VARCHAR(50)UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    DATA_NASC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    GENERO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ESTA_CIVIL VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    FOTO VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    ID_DEPARTAMENTO INT,
    ID_MUNICIPIO INT,
    DATA_HORA VARCHAR (100)NOT NULL,
    USUARIO VARCHAR (100)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC PRIMARY KEY (ID_FUNCIONARIO),

    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_MUNI FOREIGN KEY (ID_MUNICIPIO)
    REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO),

    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_DEP FOREIGN KEY (ID_DEPARTAMENTO)
    REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO (ID_DEPARTAMENTO)

)

CREATE TABLE ENDERECO
(
    ID_ENDERECO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ID_PROVINCIA INT,
    ID_MUNICIPO INT,
    RUA VARCHAR (100),
    BAIRRO VARCHAR (100),
    N_CASA VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ENDERECO PRIMARY KEY (ID_ENDERECO),
    CONSTRAINT PK_END_PROV FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROVINCIA)
    REFERENCES PROVINCIA(ID_PROVINCIA),
    CONSTRAINT PK_END_MUN FOREIGN KEY (ID_MUNICIPO)
    REFERENCES MUNICIPIO(ID_MUNICIPO)
)

CREATE TABLE PROVINCIA
(
    ID_PROVINCIA int identity(1,1),
    NOME_PROVINCIA VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PROVINCIA PRIMARY KEY(ID_PROVINCIA)
)

CREATE TABLE MUNICIPIO
(
    ID_MUNICIPO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_MUNICIPIO VARCHAR (100),
    ID_PROVINCIA INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MUNICIPO PRIMARY KEY (ID_MUNICIPO),
    CONSTRAINT PK_MUN_PROV FOREIGN KEY(ID_PROVINCIA)
     REFERENCES PROVINCIA(ID_PROVINCIA)
)

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
(
    ID_DEPARTAMENTO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_DEP VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    ID_FUNCAO INT ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEP PRIMARY KEY (ID_DEPARTAMENTO),
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEP_FUNCAO FOREIGN KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
    REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO)
)
USE PRESENCA1
CREATE TABLE FUNCAO
(
    ID_FUNCAO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_FUNCAO VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    SALARIO VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNCAO PRIMARY KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
)
```

E também na datagridviews está aparecer os Ids ao invês dos nomes

Comment: *"só que a tabela função está dentro da tabela"* como assim uma tabela dentro da tabela? isso não existe, explique melhor. Para fazer outro `join` basta acrescentar no comando `sql` outro `join`, sempre antes do `where` quando houver

Comment: Ou melhor!A tabela função é chave estrangeira na tabela departamentom eu preciso também da tebela função e também está me dar erro no insert (fazer inserto na tabela funcionário com as chaves estrangeiras)

Comment: Mario, veja que, vc criou um relacionamento entre as tabelas Departamento e função, isso vai permitir os joins, quando precisar. Já para as tabelas funcionário e departamento, vc vai precisar criar uma tabela que vai armazena os relacionamentos entre essas tabelas, tipo o idFuncionario e o IdDepto, isso vai resolver sempre que precisar relacionar um funcionario com um departamento e vice versa. Isso se aplica a outras tabelas de sua estrutura, que não possuem um relacionamento.